# Monitor all ajax request for a particular response

Tags: php, jquery

I need to monitor all the ajax responses whether it is responding the particular value in jQuery. How to do this?

Comment: And what are you going to do with this info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `ajaxSuccess` event could be your solution: http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/

if you do:

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function(event, req, options)
{
    // handle the response
});
```

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/gRoberts/NLH32/1/

Answer (score 1):

You want to monitor to test the good work of your script or monitoring for a webapp (or like) ?

If it's the first case, you can use Firebug (if you're not using it actually), but I don't think it is possible directly.
Maybe, you can add some `console.log()` in your AJAX callbacks (if you're passing objects to it, it will display all the content in Firebug).

If it's the second, you can do that :

```
    $.ajax({
       args
    }).done(function() { 
       // Treatment HERE !
    });
```

Or using the ajaxSuccess event, after an AJAX call.
See the doc [here](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/).